# PHP if query not behaving correctly

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using an if statement in PHP whereby if a query is empty it doesn't run the PHP effectivily hiding that part of the web page. This is the if statement I'm using

```
if(!empty($result4)){

}
```

It works fine elsewhere when used to hide individual empty rows from a whole result but when run for a whole query it doesn't work.

This is the whole php code everything below if(!empty($result4)){ should not happen if query is empty, but it is.

```
<?php 
if(!empty($result4)){


printf('<h2>%s News' . PHP_EOL, $row['name']);



$sLastStory = '';
foreach ($result4 AS $row4)
{
    $sStory = $row4['headline'] . $row4['story'];
    if (strcasecmp($sStory, $sLastStory) != 0)
    {
        if (!empty($sLastStory))
        {

        }
        $sLastStory = $sStory;


        printf('<h3>%s</h3>' . PHP_EOL, $row4['headline']);

        printf('<h4>%s</h4>' . PHP_EOL, $row4['Displaydate']);

        printf('<p>%s</p>' . PHP_EOL, $row4['story']);
    }

if(!empty($row4['url'])){   
printf('
<a href="/images/%s%s.jpg" rel="lightbox[%s]" title="%s - Credit - %s" >
<img src="/images/%s%s-thumb.jpg" style="max-height: 230px; max-width: 230px" alt="%s"/></a>' . PHP_EOL, $row4

['url'], $row4['alt'], $row4['headline'],  $row4['description'],$row4['credit'], $row4['url'], $row4['alt'], 

$row4['alt'] );
}

}

printf('

<br>

<hr>
<a class="bloglink" href="parknews.php?park_id=%s">See all %s news</a></li>' . PHP_EOL, $park_id, $row

['name']);

}
?>
```

Any ideas how to make it work?

If it helps this is the MySQL query:

```
$park_id = $_GET['park_id'];
$query4= 'SELECT headline, story, DATE_FORMAT(date, "%d-%M-%Y") AS Displaydate, url, alt, description, credit
FROM tpf_news 
LEFT JOIN tpf_images ON tpf_news.news_id = tpf_images.news_id 
Where tpf_news.park_id = ' .  $park_id .' ORDER BY date DESC';
$result4 = $pdo->query($query4);
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by an empty result? No rows returned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the query succeeded, `PDO::query()` will return a [`PDOStatement`](http://php.net/manual/class.pdostatement.php) even if no rows were selected. Since `$result4` contains a `PDOStatement`, it is not empty.

A better way to check the number of returned rows is [PDOStatement::rowcount](http://php.net/manual/pdostatement.rowcount.php):

```
if( $result4->rowCount() ){
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. It's my fault I'm really new to PHP but now I know how to use rowCount()  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A result of a query will never be empty, also if there are no rows matched. It could be either null or have anything else, so your condition `if(!empty($result4))` will be never satisfied. You should check for `num_rows` returned instead

```
if($result4->rowCount() > 0)
```

Comment: You need to clarify your explanation. The result of a query _can_ be empty (no rows) but the PDOStatement object returned will never satisfy `empty() != false`

Answer (score 1):

empty should not work here. If your sql statement returns no result, the PDO::query method return an object anyway : a PDOStatement. But you can use rowCount to see if your statement is empty.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a lot of choices here to `empty()`

**empty()
Determine whether a variable is considered to be empty. A variable is considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals FALSE. empty() does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist.**

to overcome this issue you need to check the number of rows returned from the query because if it has no errors it will return true

```
rowCount();
```

Check it out here

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

I hope this can help :)

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you understand the `empty()` function to do? I guess you think it should tell you whether the query has any results or not. That is not what it does.

What `empty()` does is return true if the variable (in this case `$result4`) is `null` or contains some other "empty" value.

A recordset object is not an "empty" value, regardless of how many records it got.

What you probably want to use instead for this case is

```
if($result4->rowCount() > 0)
```

See the PHP manual for [`PDOStatement::rowCount`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php).

`empty()` would only be useful here if you expected the query to fail completely -- eg an invalid query or broken DB connection. In that case, `$result4` would be `null`. But you'd also have PDO errors that you'd use to deal with that rather than checking for the recordset object being empty.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (is_array($result4) && sizeof($result4)>0) {
    // your code here!
}
```

or

```
$query4 = 'SELECT headline, story, DATE_FORMAT(date, "%d-%M-%Y") '
    . ' AS Displaydate, url, alt, description, credit '
    . ' FROM tpf_news '
    . ' LEFT JOIN tpf_images '
    . ' ON tpf_news.news_id = tpf_images.news_id '
    . ' Where tpf_news.park_id = ? '
    . 'ORDER BY date DESC';

$st = $pdo->prepare($query4);

// The following code can be placed in a loop

$st->execute(array($_GET['park_id']));

if ($st->rowCount()>0) {
    $aResult = $st->fetch();
    // your code

}
```

Marcos